# Regular expression to search word in text and not as part of a string (preg_match_all)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I hope anyone can help me with this question.

What I'm looking for is to search a string for a word

```
$text = 'is Apple, name testintapple test APPLE name test';
preg_match_all('/apple/i', $text, $output_array);
```

Return

```
array(
0   =>  Apple
1   =>  apple
2   =>  APPLE
)
```

I would like this to just return:

```
array(
0   =>  Apple
1   =>  APPLE
)
```

Comment: I know your question is answered, but I leave you a simple website where you can learn and try regexps to apply in your application https://regex101.com/

Comment: @Chaturrin Can you please check answer and upvote / accept if it solves your problem?

Answer (score 4):

What you need is:

```php
preg_match_all('/\bapple\b/i', $text, $output_array);
```

The `\b` is a word boundary. So it will only match if `apple` is used as a word an not a part of a bigger string.